# How do I update a date by a random number of days using MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, date, random

Here is what I have so far

```
update review set date_added = date_add( date_added, floor( rand() * 30 ) DAY   ) where review_id = 8;
```

I am trying to change the date by a random number of days between 0 and 30. What do I need to change this query to make it work?

Comment: So you have it... and? Any particular question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter `DATE_ADD` function accepts should look like

```
INTERVAL expr unit
```

where `INTERVAL` keyword is a **required** part.

So it's likely this:

```
date_add(date_added, INTERVAL floor(rand() * 30) DAY)
```

should work for you